# C# class and member attributes overhead

Tags: c#, .net

I am making some library (.NET C#), mostly generated code, which would heavily rely on attributes of classes and class members. I am not sure how is this implemented in language and on which levels this could affect performance compared to same code with no attributes at all. Each class and member could have about 4-5 attributes.

I guess library will be bigger a bit, this can affect loading time and maybe some obscure performance issues due to more page faults in cache.

Also, maybe some functions using reflection could execute a bit slower.

Is there any other possible performance issue? I guess that all other operations performed which are not using reflection with this code should have same performance as code with no attributes.

Comment: It's just static data, so there won't be any overhead other than what you already mentioned.

Comment: I don't think that this can be answered in general - except with "it depends".

Comment: Attributes are created only when you use reflection on them. They don't exist otherwise, so no speed change. Reflecting on attributes could be slow depending on what you want to do, how many times, if you cache the results...